# Starting Activity for result clicking on tab widget

Tags: android

My problem is that I don't know how to use `TabActivity` and `TabHost` functionality to allow me to launch new Activity, which will hold all of the screen (I want to hide TabWidgets under it).

When I create TabActivity, I make a count of tabWidgets using `TabSpec` class and set for every widget it's content (intent, launching another Activity in this case).

So what should I do if I want to implement one of the widgets to launch Activity for result?

Answer (score 1):

Hey teo not really sure of what you want, but if you want a quick way to create a TabActivity you can check this:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

Comment: You don't understand my problem I know API, which need to interact with tabs, but I want to launch an `Activity`, clicking on `TabWidget`so that this `Activity` covers `TabHost` and `TabHost` begin to lies under it.

Comment: Can't you pass a reference (of your TabHost) when you start the new activity?

Comment: No I can't because TabHost is `TabHost` and I need to pass `Context` as parameter)))